# Was Tom Paris on “Star Trek: Voyager” based on the character Nick Locarno from “Star Trek: The Next Generation?”

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager

In the *Star Trek: Next Generation* episode "[The First Duty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_First_Duty)" Robert Duncan McNeill plays a character called Nick Lacarno, who as part of Nova Squadron flight team caused an accident which resulted in the death of another cadet. He was dishonorably discharged for lying and trying to cover it up.

McNeill then went on to play Tom Paris in *Star Trek: Voyager* with a very similar background, but with some very small differences: Like Tom was an actual Starfleet officer, whereas Nick was only a Cadet.

So was Tom Paris' character based on Nick Locarno?

Comment: It seems odd that Locarno is considered irredeemable but Paris is not. They both got people killed and chose to lie about it. It seems that they had quite similar moral conundrums, except that Locarno went to prison rather than let his whole team get expelled. The only reasonable explanation listed here is the royalties that would have to be paid.

Comment: Agreed number 1 (commenter). He had shown some character. Crusher: "They should have expelled all of us." Picard: "They very nearly did. Mr Locarno made an impassioned plea for the rest of you. He said he used his influence as squadron leader to convince you to attempt the Kolvoord maneuver and then to cover up the truth. He asked to take full responsibility." Crusher: "He did exactly what he said he would. He protected the team."

Comment: My mental canon is that Tom wanted to prove himself without his family name due to his father being an admiral so he went by the name Locarno at the academy.

Comment: @AlonzoMuncy: And he eventually became a StarFleet officer after being dishonorably discharged... how?

Comment: @Ellesedil exactly how we see in the series. Remember, even without my headcanon, Tom was also  dishonorably discharged for a very similar incident.

Comment: @AlonzoMuncy: So, you're saying that a Cadet that was thrown out of StarFleet Academy would be given a field commission of lieutenant? Poor Harry Kim.

Comment: @Ellesedil Even without my headcanon, someone who got dishonorably discharged got promoted over Kim.

Comment: The royalty thing has happened before on Star Trek. They originally wanted the Vulcan woman on Enterprise (played by Jolene Blalock) to be a younger version of "T'Pau" from the Star Trek Original Series episode "Amok Time." When they realized every episode of Enterprise would pay royalties to writers of "Amok Time" they changed the character's name to "T'Pol."

Comment: @user54313: "They both got people killed and chose to lie about it." - Locarno got people killed by being intentionally reckless (he encouraged his entire group to fly a maneuver that was forbidden for safety reasons, and with no good reason - just to show off). Paris, on the other hand, committed a piloting error while flying somewhere he was indeed supposed to fly.

Comment: Are you from the Writer’s Guild? If so no, no not at all, totally different character.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is likely that it was originally intended to be Locarno on Voyager, but that once they considered the financial aspect of it, Locarno likely became the prototype for Robert Duncan McNeill's Tom Paris, rather than a direct feed. There has not been a definitive answer on the exact intent, but from the Memory Alpha page:

http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Nicholas_Locarno#Background

> Locarno was the inspiration for Star Trek: Voyager's Tom Paris. In interviews, the producers of Voyager claimed Locarno's actions made him irredeemable, and therefore a new character was required.

Comment: Because we all know that Star Trek is all about characters who are irredeemable...

Comment: Not to go off on a tangent, but I had no idea that royalties were owed to screenwriters if a one-time character from their work was reused. Very interesting if true.

Comment: Seems silly to me but I guess that's what unions are for.

Comment: Cue @tangooversway to talk about his Star Trek writing experiences.

Comment: The 'royalties' thing seems like bunk. The cost of having him be Locarno rather than a new character called Tom Paris is less than $600 per episode; http://www.wga.org/uploadedFiles/writers_resources/contracts/min2014.pdf

Comment: Even if the royalties are low, they still need to be paid and there could be other contractual responsibilities which might require lawyers. I think it would have been cool to have a character that was in TNG even briefly, but studios might not see the point in having this complication when they could just create a new character.

Comment: Until the age of the Internet, I always thought it was *LeCarneau* or *LeCarnot*, giving an extra connection to *Paris*.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: With *Locarno* being a place name, too, there *is* already some pretty direct connection to *Paris*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper:   Well, that is Italian-speaking Switzerland.   Not as satisfying.   Incidentally, I'm reminded of *Author, Author* where the Paris spoof is named *Lt. Marseilles*.   :)

Comment: The only thing, in my opinion, that distinguished the two was that the audience actually witnessed Locarno's sins whereas Paris' took place off camera.  I don't know why that constitutes him being irredeemable.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt One important difference is that the first time we meet Paris, Janeway asks him why he *confessed* and turned himself in. Locarno was convinced to the end that he was completely right and it was Wesley Crusher who betrayed him.