# What was the in-universe explanation for Tom Paris looking exactly like Nick Locarno in “Star Trek: Voyager?”

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, character-development

Okay, let’s forget about [the backstory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12735/14850) of [Tom Paris](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tom_Paris) in *Star Trek: Voyager* being supposedly more “redeemable” than that of [Nick Locarno](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nick_Locarno) in the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode “[The First Duty](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_First_Duty_(episode))” (S05E19). Either that or Tom Paris was created because of behind-the-scenes politics involved a supposed writer/producer dispute for royalties.

### Forget about all that!

#### I accept that Tom Paris and Nick Locarno are two distinct human beings with hopes and dreams of their own!

Why then do the crew of the USS Voyager or the USS Enterprise never seem to acknowledge — or freak out that — both characters are physically the same! Yes, [Robert Duncan McNeill](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Robert_Duncan_McNeill) plays the same character with not even a change in color to his hair; they literally look the same because it is played by the same exact actor with very little change in appearance.

But how is this all explained in the shared *Voyager*/*Enterprise* universe? Nobody noticed? Even in passing? [Starfleet](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet) computers didn’t even notice the difference?

Pictured: Tom Paris (left) and Nick Locarno (right).

[image: Tom Paris] [image: Nick Locarno]

---

***In-universe explanation preferred, but any “behind the scenes” discussions like, “Eh… Who cares about Nick Locarno? He’s Tom Paris now!” would be acceptable as well.***

Comment: Why should they notice? Locarno incident was not widely known and happened during different time at a different place.

Comment: again, why should they notice? This guy who ended up going to the Maquis after becoming a Starfleet officer looks a lot like the guy who screwed up in the Starfleet academy years ago and is still in prison? We don't know how often starfleet officers joining the Maquis happens. More than once, less than 50% that's for sure.

Comment: Are you seriously expecting this has been answered in-universe? I mean, no-one in STIII commented on the fact that Saavik had suddenly drastically changed in appearance, either.

Comment: Nick Locarno was never mentioned on _Voyager_, so there's no indication that any of the Voyager crew even know who he is.

Comment: We do not discuss it with outsiders.

Comment: Oh come on, they are clearly two different people. The first guy (Nick? Tom?) has a blue background and the other guy (Tom? Nick?) has a purple-ish background.  There's no way you could mistake one for the other.

Comment: It *did* come up on *Lower Decks*, in which Locarno reappears as a villain.  But just a throwaway joke about how the two characters look the same.

Comment: It's not uncommon for guest stars to later get a regular role as a different character (probably happened several times on NCIS). They practically never acknowledge the resemblance.

Comment: Armin Shimerman played two different Ferengis in two different TNG episodes before playing Quark in DS9 (and a TNG and a Voyager episode). Of course he probably looked slightly different in these roles, but so did Worf over time playing the same role.

Comment: @idspispopd Marc Alaimo also played multiple Cardassians.

Comment: After over 50 years, no-one asks about an in-universe explanation for why Spock's father Sarek (first seen in TOS:"Journey to Babel") looks exactly like the Romulan commander in TOS:"Balance of Terror".

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In-universe the resemblance is noticed by some, but not considered particularly remarkable by people very familiar with them. In the *Star Trek: Lower Decks* episode "[Old Friends, New Planets](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Old_Friends,_New_Planets_(episode))" there's this dialogue:

> Rutherford: "He looks like Tom Paris"
>
> Boimler: "I don't see it."

And this:

> Rutherford: "They have, like, the same face! They're identical!"
>
> Boimler: "No, I just don't see it."

Note that while Rutherford is aware of Paris as a very famous officer, Boimler is an obsessed fan. So apparently to the casual observer, Paris and Locarno look alike, someone who knows them very well sees all the differences and doesn't consider the resemblance to be  particularly strong.

Comment: I consider things like this to be an in-joke, an easter egg to long-time fans who know that the same actor played both characters.

Comment: See also: the "Lampshade Hanging" trope

Comment: As soon as "Nick Locarno" was mentioned in that episode I started preemptively laughing knowing that *someone* was going to bring it up at least once.

Comment: Strong disagree with the last sentence. Boimler is notorious for being unobservant and wrong. There was even an ep in S1 where one of his friends felt the need to make up a problem and pretend not to notice so Boimler could be the one to notice and make him feel better. Rutherford is most episodes is quite the opposite, and a perpetual [Cassandra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra) figure.

Comment: Citing _Lower Decks_ for evidence regarding questions about _Star Trek_ is like citing Bill Nye for questions on quantum mechanics or astrophysics. The information is not likely to be the most reliable. As @Barmar said, this is a great easter egg, and not much more. Still, +1.

Comment: @SovereignInquiry If [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_canon) says it, it must be true: "Star Trek: Lower Decks and Star Trek: Prodigy are both fully accepted as canonical as well." :)

Comment: @Barmar, Well, yes, it is "fully canonical"--and definitely more canonical than _Star Trek: Discovery_ ever could be--but it is still comedically exaggerated. Maybe not quite as bad as Bill Nye, though.

Comment: @SovereignInquiry Now you prompted me to look for a link between Nye and ST. Turns out Robert Picardo's ex-wife spread rumors that Picardo and Nye were having a gay affair. https://www.tmz.com/2014/08/05/star-trek-actor-robert-picardo-divorce-linda-pawlik-bill-nye/

Comment: @Barmar Well, that's ridiculous. And certainly comedic.

Answer (score 31):

Okay… This started off as a comment, but I think it's actually an answer.

I once had a girlfriend, and she had mentioned that there was someone in the same town that was her look-alike. Then one day I sat down at restaurant with some other people… And there was her look-alike. I spent a large part evening staring at her because I couldn't believe it.

Because this phenomena does exist we even have a word for it: [Doppelgänger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelg%C3%A4nger)

For amusement see: [“50 Strangers That Met Their Real-Life Doppelgangers”](https://www.boredpanda.com/doppelgangers-lookalikes-meet-in-real-life/).

So having two different people (in-universe) who look alike is not impossible even in our current 8.18 billion people on Earth.

Comment: Huh, that happens to me all the time. And would you believe it, my twin brother says the same thing!

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun What?  You both have GFs that look like each other?  Are you sure you aren't dating twins?

Comment: @PeterM - No, but wait until she finds out...

Comment: I had that happen to me once where a person was convinced I was someone else, only to find out years later I have a half-brother who does, in fact, look quite a bit like me.

Comment: @PeterM our partners have partners that look alike. They aren't the twins, we are. Well okay, _my_ spouse is actually a twin too, but _her_ twin looks nothing like her, so I can easily tell them apart, based on her twin being bald and bearded.

Answer (score 6):

Pretend you're a member of Starfleet.

You're familiar with a case of a cadet named Locarno, who killed a member of his squad in an accident, covered it up, and was then expelled by Starfleet. Maybe you've even seen a picture of him at the time in the Starfleet news service.

You're later posted on the *Voyager*. There's a guy named Paris walking around. He looks a LOT like the photo you say three years earlier. People whisper that this guy Paris killed three members of his crew through pilot error, was caught covering it up, and was dishonorably discharged.

Which of these two explanations would you jump to:

1. My God, what a bizarre coincidence! Two people, who look exactly the same, and have almost exactly the same biography??

   Or…
2. I remember that story! Although I guess I misremembered some of the details.

Probably number 2, right?

As for Starfleet computers, unless we're assuming that Paris and Locarno are identical down the cellular and atomic level or something, it'd be a piece of cake for them to distinguish the two. Most *humans* can spot differences in identical twins, and in-universe these are just two people who look like each other.